# Filtering out meaningless phrases

Tags: nlp

I have an algorithm (that I can't change) that outputs a list of phrases. These phrases are intended to be "topics". However, some of them are meaningless on their own. Take this list:

```
is the fear
freesat
are more likely to
first sight
an hour of
sue apple
depression and
itunes
```

How can I filter out those phrases that don't make sense on their own, to leave a list like the following?

```
freesat
first sight
sue apple
itunes
```

This will be applied to sets of phrases in many languages, but English is the priority.

Comment: How do you define "does not make sense"? "itunes", for example, doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @EmilVikström I had a go at defining it for the question and failed. It's got to be grammatically acceptable in that it can't rely on other words in the original sentence that it was extracted from; e.g. it can't end in 'and'. Imagine a list of topics for discussion - in that context "itunes" is a topic that can be discussed, "first sight" is verging on it, but "is the fear" isn't - it doesn't make sense standing on it's own.

Answer (score 3):

> It's got to be grammatically acceptable in that it can't rely on other words in the original sentence that it was extracted from; e.g. it can't end in 'and'.

Although this is still an underspecified question, it sounds like you want some kind of grammar checker. I suggest you try applying a part-of-speech tagger to each phrase, compile a list of patterns of POS tags that are acceptable (e.g. anything that ends in a preposition would be unacceptable) and use that to filter your input.

Answer (score 2):

At a high level, it seems that phrases which were only nouns or adjective-noun combos would give much better results.

Examples:

- "Blue Shirt"
- "Happy People"
- "Book"

First of all, this problem can be as complex as you want it to be. For third-party reading/solutions, I came across:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_language_processing_toolkits
- http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/groups/nlp/
- http://sharpnlp.codeplex.com/ (note the part of speech tagger)

If you need 100% accuracy, then I wouldn't write such a tool myself.

However, if the problem domain is limited...

I would start by throwing out conjunctions, prepositions, contractions, state-of-being verbs, etc. This is a fairly short list in English (and looks very similar to the stopwords which @HappyTimeGopher suggested).

After that, you could create a dictionary (as an indexed structure, of course) of all acceptable nouns and adjectives and compare each word in the raw phrases to that. Anything which didn't occur in the dictionary and occur in the correct sequence could be thrown out or ranked lower.

This could be useful if you were given 100 input values and wanted to select the best 5. Finding the values in the dictionary would mean that it's likely the word/phrase was good.

I've auto-generated such a dictionary before by building a raw index from thousands of documents pertaining to a vertical industry. I then spent a few hours with SQL and Excel stripping out problems easily spotted by a human. The resulting list wasn't perfect but it eliminated most of the blatantly dumb/pointless terminology.

As you may have guessed, none of this is foolproof, although checking adjective-to-noun sequence would help somewhat. Consider the case of "Greatest Hits" versus "Car Hits [Wall]".

Proper nouns (e.g. person names) don't work well with the dictionary approach, since it's probably not feasible to build a dictionary of all variations of given/surnames.

To summarize:

- use a list of stopwords
- generate a dictionary of words, classifying them with a part of speech(s)
- run raw phrases through dictionary and stopwords
- (optional) rank on how confident you are on a match
- if needed, accept phrases which didn't violate known patterns (this would handle many proper nouns)

Answer (score 1):

If you've access to the text these phrases were generated from, it may be easier to just create your own topic tags.

Failing that, I'd probably just remove anything that contained a stop word. See this list, for example:
http://www.ranks.nl/resources/stopwords.html

I wouldn't break out POS tagging or anything stronger for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you could create a list that filters out three things:

1. Prepositions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_English_prepositions
2. Conjunctions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)
3. Verb forms of to-be: http://www.englishplus.com/grammar/00000040.htm

If you filter on these things you'd get pretty far. Are you more concerned with false negatives or positives? If false negatives aren't a huge problem, this is how I would approach it.